# javascript Canvas Animation with setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in my code it dont work and i dont find the misstakes i think the misstakes is because the many nesting and i have set a bracket on the wrong place.
The Function from the code is a Animation in the Animation are some images at the top of the canvas and than should this images slowly came from the top to the bottom like a watterfall.i hope you can understand my explanation.

```
console.log("hey");
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); //ctx = contex
                var img = new Image();
                img.src="../img/cookie.png";

            canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth;
            canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight;


img.onload = function() {
                console.log("Loaded image")
                var add = 10;
                var id  = setInterval(function () {

                        if (add == 500) {

                                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

                                    ctx.beginPath();
                                    ctx.rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
                                    ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
                                    ctx.fill();

                                    ctx.drawImage(img,0 , 0, 100, 100);
                                    ctx.drawImage(img,100,0, 100, 100);
                                    ctx.drawImage(img,200,0, 100, 100);
                                    ctx.drawImage(img,300,0, 100, 100);
                                    ctx.drawImage(img,400,0, 100, 100);
                                    ctx.drawImage(img,500,0, 100, 100);
                                    ctx.drawImage(img,600,0, 100, 100);
                                    ctx.drawImage(img,700,0, 100, 100);

        } else {

                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
                ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
                ctx.fill();

                ctx.drawImage(img,0 , add, 100, 100);
                ctx.drawImage(img,100,add, 100, 100);
                ctx.drawImage(img,200,add, 100, 100);
                ctx.drawImage(img,300,add, 100, 100);
                ctx.drawImage(img,400,add, 100, 100);
                ctx.drawImage(img,500,add, 100, 100);
                ctx.drawImage(img,600,add, 100, 100);
                ctx.drawImage(img,700,add, 100, 100);

                add++;
            }
        }, 10)
  }
```

PS:sorry if some misstakes in my text but i am still student. :D

PPS: thanks for the help.

**EDIT:** Now it works thanks for the help. 
**EDit2:**now i have a nother problem  the code will only exectude one time but it should excetuded the full time  if anybody can help me i am very danbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all of your brackets are in the right place. The big error I see is that your if statement says `if (add = 1000)` using single `=` instead of double `==`. This means that you're setting `add` to `1000` in your if statement instead of comparing it.

Edit: Another issue you had was that your image `src` was being defined in its `onload`, which doesn't really make sense, as the `onload` waits for `src` to be loaded.

I made a jsfiddle here where your code works, check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/pjkmwvp6/

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing this???

```
// Change this
if(add = 1000){

// To this
if(add === 1000){
```

Answer (score 1):

To address any doubts you may have with brackets, many editors and web services can perform code beautifying (aka pretty printing) for you. Give it a Google. Also, there’s one such tool build into Firefox with the Shift+F4 “slate”, just paste your code in it and hit Ctrl+P.

I think you’re not loading your image the right way. Be aware that setting an image’s `src` attribute is what actually triggers its loading. As is, your code can’t load the image since the instruction that sets `src` is *inside* the `onload` handler. Put it after.

When dealing with animations, `setInterval` is not the best suited function. Prefer [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame). Its syntax is very close and it has CPU-saving capabilities.

Comment: ah okay that i dont know that